# How to reset nicknames of all members in the server?

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

I want to reset everyone's nickname in the server. How can I do? Which code should I use?

I'm new in coding. I didn't try anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@bot.command() # command decorator
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True) # check for change nickname permission
async def reset(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members: # loop through every member in the guild
        await member.edit(nick=None) # reset their nickname
```